# How to make an iOS app that has different UI design based on who logs in? (Firebase authentication)

Tags: ios, xcode

I heard that android themes can be used to do it for android, but what about iOS? Is it possible to have show a different UI for three different level of permissions users, or do I simply have to create 3 separate apps?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the user permission you can change the UI. For this you need to design three types of UI. If the UI change is going to be only some colors and fonts, then you can handle that in code without designing three types of UI. The login screen will have to be same for all users, because only after login you will be able to identify the user's permission.